# How can i add setting menu like controls on windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Like this 
 [image: settings menu]

Basically, I want a list in which I can select the entries to display more details for that entry.How can I do that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make use of ListBox,

```
  <ListBox Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Settings}" 
                     SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentSelectedSetting, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SettingName}"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Width="5"></TextBlock>

                            </StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Comment: ok, I am getting it. But now how do i add elements to it. Can you point me to a tutorial where i can find some details?

Comment: Post it as a separate question